# Which one would be idiomatic way to say you've been investing in a fund so you can retire later? "to be on a private fund" or "to be member of fund"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrases, idiomatic-language

1-We are on a private superannuation fund.

2-We hold a private superannuation fund.

3-We are members to a private superannuation fund.

Answer (score 1):

None of them really. I'd go with…

> We have a private pension scheme [or plan, or arrangement].

Maybe superannuation is a US term. I know exactly what one is, but it's not a term I would ever use. I did work in pensions for a decade, in my youth - in the UK.

Maybe, if superannuation is the correct term for the US, then perhaps

> We have a private superannuation scheme [or plan, or fund] - depending on exactly how it's termed over there.

We'd need a US user experienced with the terminology to confirm or correct.

Is suppose, really, you need to indicate you are 'a participant' in such plan/scheme/fund.
'Have' is a simple way of not getting too specific over exactly what 'grip' you need to assume in order to participate ;)

1. You can't really be 'on a fund'. You are a participant in one, or a contributor to one.
2. You don't hold the fund. It's not yours to hold, it belongs to the company you are investing through.
3. It's not a club, so you aren't really a member*.

*To be really pedantic, you can be a member of a 'pension scheme' - but that would preclude it being private, it would have to be a company scheme, for instance, for all employees. If you don't work in the industry, I wouldn't get that fussy over the terminology.
To be equally pedantic, the fund is not something you are ever in direct contact with. You invest in a scheme/plan/arrangement & the company deals with the fund or funds & how contributions & investments are distributed within those to get maximum yield or greatest security. Hence the term 'managed fund'.

Comment: How about _in a fund_? It sounds natural to me, but I've never worked in the field.

Comment: @ColinFine - I suppose you could get away with being 'in a fund' but really you're not 'in' it, you're 'investing in it'.

Comment: @Tetsujin  *Superannuation* is not a term I've ever run across in the US, although I am not a financial expert.  When I google it, most of the results seem to be from India, Australia, and New Zealand.

Comment: @Colin Fine, yes the text actually says "in a fund". Here is the text: A:We are on a private superannuation fund. We would like to know if we are eligible for government pension. B: It all depends on what kind of superannuation fund you have and how long you have been in it.

Comment: That's really just the replier using the same terms as you did, to save confusion & extra explanation.